# how to get the last accessed action in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

How can I get the last accessed 'Action' in a asp.net mvc app.

Example I have a menuItem called 'Add to Favourites" when clicked is navigated to a page in which I need to populate a textbox with this url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built in mechanism to do this.  What I would do, is populate your Add To Favourites url, like so:

Create an extension method to encode the current url:

```
public static class UrlHelperExtensions
{
    public static string AddToFavourites(this UrlHelper helper)
    {
        return helper.RouteUrl("AddToFavourites", new { url = EncodeUrl() });
    }

    private static string EncodeUrl()
    {
        var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
        string url = request.Url.ToString();

        return Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(url));
    }
}
```

Then wire up your action:

```
public ActionResult AddToFavourites(string url)
{
    url = Encoding.Default.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(url));

    return View(url);
}
```

Make sure you have a route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "AddToFavourites",
    "Home/AddToFavourites/{url}", new { url = (string)null });
```

And then you can use the helper in your menu:

```
<a href="<%= Url.AddToFavourites() %>">Add To Favourites</a>
```

Hope that helps?

Answer (score 1):

Override base controller OnActionExecuted and save action there (for example in Session).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's an asp.net MVC question. Here your "Action" refers an URL right? You can use JavaScript `document.referrer` to get the last visited URL.